# Azure SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, azure, authorization

I published my web application on Azure and I face problem with `SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified`. I dont know exactly why this happens since when I published my application on another server, it works fine.

My connection string is definitely correct, since I receive Access token from my application without any problem.

Here I include stack trace: https://pastebin.com/aqT3yCdw

This is my angular method where I send request to API for my token and If I get it I pass my token into request header and redirect to my dashboard and I guess according to stack trace it somehow might lose credentials and application will not sign in user and relocation to my secured dashboard will fail. Problem is, I cant figure out, why this works somewhere and somewhere it doesnt. Could someone explain to me what might cause this problem?

```
 $scope.signIn = function () {
        var params = "grant_type=password&username=" + $scope.username + "&password=" + $scope.password;
        $http({
            url: '/Token',
            method: "POST",
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
            data: params
        })
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            currentUser.setProfile(data.userName, data.Image, data.access_token);
            $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = "Bearer " + data.access_token;
            window.location = "/Dashboard#/";
        })
        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
           // Notification.error(data.error);
            $scope.showMessage = true;
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

> I published my web application on Azure and I face problem with SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified. I dont know exactly why this happens since when I published my application on another server, it works fine.

Firstly, please make sure if someone specify the connection string under [Application Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-configure) blade (which would override your existing entries where the key equals the linked database name) in the Azure portal.

Secondly, please [remote debug your web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio#a-nameremotedebugaremote-debugging-web-apps) to check the actual value of Server&Instance that code are accessing and make sure the server and instance name are correct.

Thirdly, please make sure you enabled [Azure connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-firewall-configure) to allow applications from Azure to connect to your Azure SQL server.

Comment: Hi, I find out after some time, that I had to put `<remove name="RoleManager" />` into my `web.config` file. About debugging, I use VS2015 and there is some known bug with remote debug which is now impossible to use.