# Azure SQL Server database connection issue. error:26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specific

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service, razor-pages

I made a project on ASP.NET Razor Pages [here](https://razorpagesdemoapp.azurewebsites.net/) and it has basic database functionality (crud). I was able to upload my project onto azure to host it but when I navigate to the "List of Employees" page, I get the error mentioned in the title. This is the full message:

SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SNI_PN11, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 2022 and Visual Studio 2022

I looked on multiple forums here on stack and even consulted the Microsoft docs on the web and couldn't fix the issue. I tried the following:

- Adding ip firewall rules on azure portal
- Adding ip firewall rules on my machine to allow connection to port 1433 inbound and outbound
- I set the IPALL Port to 1433 inside SQL Configuration Manager for protocols to my instance
- I changed the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to "Production" from "Development"
- Allowed remote connections
- Setting my connection string in appsettings.json to : IPADDRESS\SQLEXPRESS instead of MYMACHINE\SQLEXPRESS

I've seen a couple of posts saying stuff about changing something in the web.config file but, my project never came with a web.config file since the moment I created it. I know I can add it but, not sure what to do with it.

I've had no luck. I'm self taught and learning still. This is my first ASP.NET project I upload onto Azure. I've had some test projects I've done in the past and have had the same luck. If this is how it's going to go every time I want to host a web app with a database on Azure I'm truly going to just not make web apps with databases.

Comment: Best way of finding issue is to use SQL Server Management Studio which gives better error messages than using c#.  Start SSMS from same machine where the c# connection is running.  The login window of SSMS has the instance and the credentials (either Window or SQL).  Put in the login window same parameter you are using in the connection string.  Integrated Security = true in the connection string is Window Credentials.  If you are able to connect with SSMS check the log files in the explorer under Management which should show any login failure from your c# application.

Comment: I guess I should've mentioned that this is all running from one single machine. I did what you said and checked the logs and I'm not seeing any login issues. Is there something else I can try? Should my database name in the connection string be the azure db or my local db that I created on my machine? At first I use the local db but not sure if that's something I should change once the web app is on azure sql.

Comment: The connection string should be the same as SSMS login window.  The connection string should not have both LocalDb and Server.  LocalDb is when the mdf file is NOT attached to the server.  Server is when the mdf file is attached.  Do you see a login in the logs when c# is run?

Comment: Double checked and my connection string is indeed the same as login window. But no I don't see any login data within the current logs. I tried connecting to the page that's giving me an issue and refreshed the logs and still getting nothing. BTW, this is what my connection string looks like in appsettings.json: "server=JUPIDNESS\\SQLEXPRESS;database=RazorPagesDemoDb;trusted_connection=true;TrustServerCertificate=True"

Comment: Is the instance on the SSMS login screen "JUPIDNESS\\SQLEXPRESS"?  It must be exactly the same.  You should see in the log files an attempted connection.   The certificate may also be an issue.  See following for certificate issues : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/manage-certificates?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: It is but it isn't? In login its only "JUPIDNESS\SQLEXPRESS", one backslash. In connection string it's the way you saw with 2 backslashes. It needs 2 backslashes in connection string because if not, it will read it as an attempted escape sequence .Ok so we're getting somewhere. I checked the certificate you're talking about and it originally wasn't set to anything. I have two available certificates from the drop down the first one is "ASP.NET Core HTTPS development certificate" and the second one is "IIS Express Development Certificate"

Comment: I always use a `@` instead of two backslashes.  If you do not see the login with c# in the logs than you are not connecting.  It probably the certificate.  With a certificate you use TLS for the connection.  TLS is performed before the connection completes to establish an encrypted connection.  Check the Event Viewer and see if there are any error at time c# is run.  What OS?  Check the Certificate Requirements in the link above.  The encryption mode of the certificate may not work with OS.  Where did you get the certificate?  Is certificate signed?

Comment: `my project never came with a web.config`, Once you deploy the application to Azure App Service ,web.config file will be generated automatically in the application root folder `site\wwwroot`.You can check it in KUDU Console

Comment: Ok @jdweng I tried the @ but didn't really get it to work anyway. In terms of the OS, I'm using Windows and in terms of the certificate, I have truly no idea. Everything I've done has been through tutorials on youtube or different websites. I have no idea where I'd even start to figure out information about certificates.

Comment: @Harshitha I just checked wwwroot and it isn't there.

Comment: Can you please share the screen shot

Comment: Use the link I provided to configure the certificate.  Yoiur connection string has TrustServerCertificate=True"  TLS will fail when making the connection if the certificate is not configured properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are connecting an Azure SQL database to your project, you can find the connection string of the database in the portal, as shown below:

[image]

Ensure that you have configured the correct connection string of database. Along with that, make sure you have checked **Allow Azure services and resources to access this server** in the Azure SQL server firewall settings, as shown below:

[image]

For more information, you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43490663/azure-sql-network-interfaces-error-26).

Comment: Okay. It works! It was the connection string! I had my connection string set to the connection string for my local machine. I had to change the connection string to the one Azure Portal provides and just put in my password. Web app works perfectly now. Thanks for your help! Also thank you @jdweng for your help also. For people visiting this post later, make sure your connection string in appsettings.json is the same connection string azure portal gives you for the Azure database!